# Current date time in specific timezone with and without DST offset with NodaTime

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I need to sync a device internal clock on a device according to which timezone the users has selected. 
I'm using the following code to get the current time for that zone with respect to the system clock:

```
var currentInstant = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant().InZone(userTimezone);
```

But I also need to be able to toggle a flag that enables/disables DST for the zone, meaning if the zone currently has DST active I need to be able to subtract the offset it adds, and only set the internal clock to the zone time with the standard offset.

I found the standard offset with (not 100% this is correct though):

```
currentInstant.GetZoneInterval().StandardOffset;
```

But I'm not sure how to get the zone time using it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *why* you think you need a flag to enable/disable DST?  That is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: I know it isn't but the client insists on it, after several failed rounds of convincing him it's a bad idea, I'm stuck with the requirement. The current app he uses has this functionality.

Comment: Time zones are hard.  Most people don't get that.  Ask your client if they can tell you a place in the world where DST is presently in use but some people choose not to observe it.  Also, ask them how they would like to handle the scenario of when a government says they are going to "permanent DST" but what they actually mean is that they're switching their standard time.

Comment: Oh, you should also watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg  ;)

Comment: I did this morning, a couple of times :), just so I feel a little better. And I drew a bird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're nearly there. You presumably want the `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`, which you'd get like this:

```
var now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
var zoneInterval = zone.GetZoneInterval(now);
var offset = zoneInterval.StandardOffset; // Ignore any savings
OffsetDateTime offsetNow = now.WithOffset(offset);
```

You can get the `LocalDateTime` with `offsetNow.LocalDateTime` if you need that.

At that point, you don't have a `ZonedDateTime`, because you don't really have a time zone as such - your "zone without DST" isn't a regular time zone. But it sounds like it's what you need.

As Matt said, this is a fundamentally bad idea - I know you've tried to convince your client of that already, but it's probably worth thinking ahead and working out what you'll do when your client understands that it's a bad idea too...

Comment: Thanks @Jon, it's used in an access controls system, so I'm thinking he's aware (at least in part) of the problems that can arise, and the use is some special case or something.